# How to make rain look like snow in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Tis' the season, and I'm making a Minecraft Christmas resource pack, and I'm trying to make the rain look like snow. I've tried renaming all the files to do with snow to "rain" and putting them in the environment folder in the textures folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't think of the command right now, I think it's something like "setbiome"? I beleive you can change the biome to a tundra (or similar cold biome)

Answer (score -1):

For Windows
Are you using Windows?
Put everything back how it was, then just change the textures in the Weather.png file to snowflakes. If you are not using Windows or need any additional help, just reply back.